# AspNetUserClaims remove all item ClaimType

Tags: asp.net-identity, claims

With my Identity in asp core 3.1 (with EFCOre) i have create all tables AspUser for manage user.

Now i have a lot of data in AspNetUserClaims. I need to remove all item with ClaimType=='NodePermission', but the only way to remove is get all user and remove this value one by one with the Usermanage.RemoveClaim(user, claim);

there is a massive operation for delete all Claims in AspNetUserClaims? The only way I found is to use a SQL query instead of using the Manager class or EFCore. But I don't like much.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can use DeleteRange/RemoveRange function. Also you may research about Bulk functions.

```
UserManager.UserClaims.DeleteRange(NodePermissionUserList);
```